# JavaScript Convert Blob to Float32Array (or other Typed Arrays)

Tags: javascript, websocket

How do you convert a blob that was received with a WebSocket Binary message to a Float32Array (or other Typed Arrays : Uint32, Uint16, etc).

I've tried to use the FileReader but the 'result' takes WAY too long to become available.  The result MUST be available on the next received WebSocket message.

If I could get the WebSocket to receive an ArrayBuffer instead of a Blob, that would work.  How can I do that?

Comment: You can do it synchronously with a bit of a hack, like I describe [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27208593/1615483). This still won't be guaranteed to be before some independent async thing. Maybe take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15040126/receiving-websocket-arraybuffer-data-in-the-browser-receiving-string-instead

Comment: @Paul - interesting hack.  I found the soln posted below, thanks.  Just don't use a Blob ;)

Answer (score 7):

Found the solution, is was easy.  The WebSocket binaryType default is 'Blob', change it to ArrayBuffer and then convert data to other TypedArrays is fast.

```
var ws = new WebSocket(...);
ws.binaryType = 'arraybuffer';
ws.onmessage = wsevent;
```

The message handler might look like this:

```
var floatArray;
function wsevent(event) {
  if (event.data instanceof ArrayBuffer) {
    floatArray = new Float32Array(event.data);
    return;
  }
  //...handle other ws messages
}
```

In my code I typically send the binary data in one message and then the next text message would use the binary data.

Comment: hey, I'm having a similar issue. Could you please elaborate, how to go from ArrayBuffer to Float32Array? I'm new to typed arrays, having some difficulties with it. Thanks!

Comment: @Andrei I've expanded the sample code to show how it's done.